# Loading, parsing, and displaying a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I recently have been working on loading a local JSON file parsing it and displaying it using Javascript and I think I got it to where I really like it. I would like to know if anyone knows if there is a "purer" way of doing this using just Javascript without libraries.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" accept=".json"/>
<output id="list"></output>
<div id="traveler_num"></div>
<div id="first_name"></div>

<script>

  //stores the output of a parsed JSON file
  const parsed = jsonText => JSON.parse(jsonText);
  //creates a new file reader object
  const fr = new FileReader();

  function writeInfo (data) {
    //modifies the DOM by writing info into different elements
    document.getElementById('traveler_num').innerHTML = 'Traveler: ' + data.traveler_num;
    document.getElementById('first_name').innerHTML = 'First Name: ' + data.first_name;
  };

  function handleFileSelect (evt) {
    //function is called when input file is Selected
    //calls FileReader object with file
    fr.readAsText(evt.target.files[0])
  };

  fr.onload = e => {
    //fuction runs when file is fully loaded
    //parses file then makes a call to writeInfo to display info on page
    writeInfo(parsed(e.target.result));
  };

  //event listener for file input
  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

</script>
```

Comment: To prevent racing i would move the FileReader instantiation and the onload handler inside handleFileSelect. However the whole thing looks fine, good job ;)

Comment: You already did it fine without any libraries?

Comment: Seems fine, but relying on the file's extension is a poor move IMO. You should at least wrap the JSON.parse in a try catch block.

Answer (score 2):

## `handleFileSelect` is an [Impure Function](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide-old/content/ch3.html)

`handleFileSelect` has in your code snippet a dependence to `fr` which is decleraded outside of the function. To make the function pure you can pass `fr` as argument.

```
// impure..
function handleFileSelect (evt) {
    fr.readAsText(evt.target.files[0])
}

// pure
function handleFileSelect (fr, evt) {
    fr.readAsText(evt.target.files[0])
}
```

## Put Side Effects Into a [Wrapper](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide-old/content/ch8.html#old-mcdonald-had-effects)

> A pure function returns for the same input always the same output.

The function `writeInfo` contains side effects because we access the DOM. We could wrap the DOM functions in to a wrapper called [`IO`](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide-old/content/ch8.html#old-mcdonald-had-effects) which will always return a function - *always the same function*.

```js
const IO = x => ({
    map: (fn) => IO(x(fn)),
    run: () => x()
})

// more about compose and the benefits on
// https://medium.com/javascript-scene/composing-software-an-introduction-27b72500d6ea
const compose = (f, g) => x => f(g(x))

const getElementById = id => IO(() => document.getElementById(id))
const writeInnerHTML = value => element => IO(() => element.run().innerHTML = value)

const selectAndWrite = value => compose(
  writeInnerHTML(value),
  getElementById
)

const writeInfo = data => IO(() => {
  selectAndWrite('Traveler: ' + data.traveler_num)('traveler_num').run()
  selectAndWrite('First Name: ' + data.first_name)('first_name').run()
})

// ONLY this call is impure
writeInfo({
  traveler_num: 500,
  first_name: 'Steven'
}).run()
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="traveler_num"></li>
  <li id="first_name"></li>
<ul>
```

## [Either](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide-old/content/ch8.html#pure-error-handling) You Can Parse to a JSON or Not..

In the following I want to introduce a [functor](https://medium.com/@dtinth/what-is-a-functor-dcf510b098b6) calles [Either](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide-old/content/ch8.html#pure-error-handling) which is split into to functors `Left` and `Right`. If we can parse a string succesfully we will return a `Right` with the parsed value otherwise we will return `Left` with an error message.

```js
const Left = x => ({
  map: (fn) => Left(x),
  get: () => x
})

const Right = x => ({
  map: (fn) => Right(fn(x)),
  get: () => x
})

const tryFunction = (errorMessage, fn) => x => {
  try {
    return Right(fn(x))
  } catch (error) {
    return Left(errorMessage)
  }
}

const parseToJson = tryFunction('Can\'t pase to JSON', JSON.parse)

console.log('should be {"name": "Random Name"}:', parseToJson('{"name": "Random Name"}').get())
console.log('should be "Can\'t pase to JSON":', parseToJson('{name: Random Name}').get())
```

## References

The free online book [mostly-adequate-guide](https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide-old/content/) is very good
The series [composing-software](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/composing-software-an-introduction-27b72500d6ea) is a good way to start

Comment: This is fantastic! I am stumbling through most of the code, but from what I can tell this is exactly what I am looking for. Do you mind maybe going a bit more in-depth on the how/why of things. Or list a reference material and I can learn myself. Seriously this is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I add two ressources

Answer (score 1):

If by functional mean arrow functions, then this is the solution i came up with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" accept=".json"/>
<output id="list"></output>
<div id="traveler_num"></div>
<div id="first_name"></div>

<script>
    (function () {
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        const travelerNumElement = document.getElementById('traveler_num');
        const firstNameElement = document.getElementById('first_name');

        this.writeInfo = (data) => {
            travelerNumElement.innerHTML = 'Traveler: ' + data.traveler_num;
            firstNameElement.innerHTML = 'First Name: ' + data.first_name;
        }

        this.handleFileSelect = (event) => fileReader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);

        fileReader.onload = (event) => this.writeInfo(JSON.parse(event.target.result));

        document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    })();
</script>
```

Always wrap things in `(function() { //code here })` when you are using ES5, because it prevents the global scope of being bloated with unnecessary variables.

You can change the `const` to `this` and write `this` everywhere in the scope, but it gets a bit ugly, so that's why i didn't do it.

And lastly, don't use abbreviations, imagine if someone else has to read the code, and the person can't see where the variable is defined, then `fr` could just as well be `flightRadar`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried my best to convert your code based on functional programming. But, I have achieved this much only without using any external library. Obviously, we can extract helper `functions` from any `fp` library like [`Ramda`](http://ramdajs.com/) but I guess that will be same as using any external library.

```js
function attachEvent(id, event, fn) {
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(event, fn, false);
}

function setInnerHTML(id, innerHTML) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = innerHTML;
}

function readFile(file) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = e => {
      resolve(e.target.result);
    };
    fr.readAsText(file)
  })
}


function handleFileSelect(e) {
  readFile(e.target.files[0]).then(c => JSON.parse(c)).then(function (obj) {
    setInnerHTML('traveler_num', 'Traveler: '.concat(obj.traveler_num));
    setInnerHTML('first_name', 'First Name: '.concat(obj.first_name));
  })
}


attachEvent('files', 'change', handleFileSelect);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" accept=".json"/>
<div id="traveler_num"></div>
<div id="first_name"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Really, your code is fine. These are mostly just nitpicks. You're already using vanilla JS with no (non-native) libraries.

- Your HTML has a doctype but no `<html>` or `<head>` or `<body>`... hopefully that's just for display and not your actual code.
- Wrap the whole thing in an IIFE so everything is not in the global scope.
- No reason to store the `handleFileSelect` in memory since it's only used once. Use an anonymous or arrow function instead.
- Put your `fr.onload` handler below the `fr` "constant" so similar code is grouped. Remove the curlies and make it a one-liner.
- The `accept` attribute is supposed to be a [comma separated list of mime types](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/input.file.html), not the extension. However, at one point they did suggest that you **also** include the extension for better browser support. I remember that from [a project I was working](https://github.com/Pamblam/fileUpload#usage) on but the page where it recommended that is now a dead link.
- Your JS should be in it's own file, not inline.

```js
(() => {

  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = e => writeInfo(parsed(e.target.result));

  const parsed = jsonText => JSON.parse(jsonText);

  function writeInfo(data) {
    //modifies the DOM by writing info into different elements
    document.getElementById('traveler_num').innerHTML = 'Traveler: ' + data.traveler_num;
    document.getElementById('first_name').innerHTML = 'First Name: ' + data.first_name;
  };

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', e => fr.readAsText(e.target.files[0]), false);

})();
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" accept="application/json, .json" />
<output id="list"></output>
<div id="traveler_num"></div>
<div id="first_name"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I wrote everything together with the intention of separating out the JS into it's own file. I like the idea of wrapping everything in an IIFE, still have to get my head around all that. Removing the handleFileSelect would have never crossed my mind, that was great. I am still very new to both javascript and functional programming so I am trying to push myself.

Comment: @JustinGagnon - doing pretty good for a newbie. pls don't forget to hit the check mark next to your favorite answer - you can also upvote other answers that you liked as well.

Comment: I have upvoted but due to my low reputation it doesn't really do anything.